# Difference echoing "" and ''?

Tags: php, html

When echoing on a php some html commands that will be used to build the website, what is the difference between these 2?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 2):

Without anything between the quotes, neither do anything useful. I suppose you're talking about using the different quote types to surround strings in general. The most significant difference is double quotes do variable interpolation and escapes, whereas single-quoted strings don't. For example:

```
$num = 5;
echo 'You have $num apples.\n'; // You have $num apples.\n
echo "You have $num apples.\n"; // You have 5 apples.[newline]
```

Single quotes do interpret escapes in a few circumstances, though:

```
echo 'It\'s interpreting these backslash \\ escapes.';
// It's interpreting these backslash \ escapes.
```

Comment: meaning `''` is literal sense right? Or a literal string rather.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: I meant if you have `echo '';` in a file without anything between the single quotes, it doesn't do anything useful.

Comment: I see what about something like this? Will the single quote consider the style parameter as well or does it ignore it? <ul style="list-style-type: none;height: 20px;width: 500px;margin: auto;">

Comment: @Patrax What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about echo shortcut method,

may be u need to see this manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Answer (score 0):

if double quotes is used, php will interpret variable name e.g. $var as a variable name and output or echo variable value.

if single quotes is used, php will treat it as a normal string.

```
$name = "Jane";

echo 'Hello $name'; // output is Hello $name
echo "Hello $name"; // output is Hello Jane
```